# Как сделать локальный доступ к серверу?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Я установил на ноут ubuntu, затем apache,php,mysql. Как сделать так чтобы к серверу я мог обращаться по локальной сети)на самом простецком языке объясните пожалуйста)Заранее спасибо)Прошу не ругаться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache в убунте после установки должен быть виден всем в сети по умолчанию

Comment: все)исправил)оказывается комп и ноут к разным сетям подсоединены были. А как расшарить в глобальной сети?

Comment: кроме способа со статическим айпи?

Comment: у вас внешний ip должен быть личный.
либо попросить администратора сети прокинуть (PREroute) 80 порт для вас.

Comment: а можно про preroute подробнее?я должен провайдера просить?

Comment: именно так